# How can I change directory back to client machine in ssh?

Tags: ssh, unix, file-transfer, scp

I'm trying to transfer files between a server and my mac using the terminal and SSH.  If I haven't already logged into the server I can simply type:
     `scp -r user@sever.domain.edu:/classes/difficultclass/bin/prog1 ~/Desktop`

However, if I've already logged into the server via SSH, this isn't going to work as the home directory is on the host machine not my client machine I'm working from.

Is there a good way I can change directory to my client mac, simply refer to it to transfer files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Your SSH session on the remote computer is equivalent to a local terminal logon so you'll have to use scp again to copy the files (i.e. scp from remote computer to your local one).

You might as well open a new terminal window and use the same command. If you want to avoid typing the password, you can use private key authentication or [reuse an SSH connection](http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-faster-connections.html).